# React: Will a state change cause an entire component to be redrawn?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I'm creating a form in react that has conditional flow. For example two input fields might be hidden when some select option is chosen. Is it a good idea to create states based on the select options and make the visibility of the input elements to depend on the current state. Or shall I add refs to the input elements and make the select cause a change event which will be used to manipulate the visibility of the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have any complicated logic for deciding whether to draw an input or not I think it's perfectly fine, even encouraged, to simply tie it to some state variable. Here's an example using Reacts two-way binding addon:

```
var MyForm = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {hasName: false};
    },

    render: function() {
        var nameInput = null;
        if (this.state.hasName) {
            nameInput = <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" />
            </label>;
        }

        return <form>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checkedLink={this.linkState('hasName')} />
                Do you have a name?
            </label>
            <br/>
            {nameInput}
       </form>;
    }
});

React.render(<MyForm/>, document.body);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p4u1qhym/

And when you're using event handlers you should still set a state variable for the input: Even though React is smart enough to keep any DOM state intact during re-rendering (e.g. a `visibility` styling option), it won't always work. Imagine for example a situation where you serialize the forms state and want to use it to initialize another form later on. React won't be able to infer that the name input should not be displayed, and renders it.

There still exist situations when it's useful to use `this.refs` however, for example when setting the focus to a particular input, as described [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

From the title of your question I assume you are worrying about performance: Yes, the entire component will be re-rendered, but only in *virtual DOM*. React then finds all the differences to the actual DOM and only applies the changes required for the two to match. You can read about it [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html#reactive-updates-are-dead-simple.). As this whole process is very efficient, there should be virtually no difference in performance to setting some style attribute on the actual DOM node using `this.refs`. And it's a lot less verbose!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well explained!